# Unexpected behavior of custom hardware design based on i.MX6 & MT41K256M16TW-107 IT:P

Tags: c++, c, linux, garbage-collection

I'm new to custom hardware designs and I'm going to scale up my custom hardware which is functioning well with few boards. I need some help with making decision on prototypes and scaling up with the state of the prototypes.

This hardware is based on i.MX6Q processor & MT41K256M16TW-107 IT:P memory. This is most similar to nitrogen6_max development board.

I'm having trouble with my hardware which is really difficult to figure out as some boards are working really well and some are not (From 7 units of production 4 boards are functioning really well, one board getting segmentation faults and kernel panic while running linux application ). When I do memory calibration of bad boards those are really looks like same to good boards.

Segmentation fault is directing to some memory issues, I back traced and core dumped using linux GDB. >>

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  gcoHARDWARE_QuerySamplerBase (Hardware=0x22193dc, Hardware@entry=0x0, 
VertexCount=0x7ef95370, VertexCount@entry=0x7ef95368, VertexBase=0x40000,
FragmentCount=FragmentCount@entry=0x2217814, FragmentBase=0x0) at 
gc_hal_user_hardware_query.c:6020
6020    gc_hal_user_hardware_query.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x76feb010 (LWP 697))]
(gdb) bt
#0  gcoHARDWARE_QuerySamplerBase (Hardware=0x22193dc, Hardware@entry=0x0, 
VertexCount=0x7ef95370, VertexCount@entry=0x7ef95368, VertexBase=0x40000,
FragmentCount=FragmentCount@entry=0x2217814, FragmentBase=0x0) at 
gc_hal_user_hardware_query.c:6020
#1  0x765d20e8 in gcoHAL_QuerySamplerBase (Hal=<optimized out>, 
VertexCount=VertexCount@entry=0x7ef95368, VertexBase=<optimized out>, 
FragmentCount=FragmentCount@entry=0x2217814,
FragmentBase=0x0) at gc_hal_user_query.c:692
#2  0x681e31ec in gcChipRecompileEvaluateKeyStates (chipCtx=0x0, 
gc=0x7ef95380) at src/chip/gc_chip_state.c:2115
#3  gcChipValidateRecompileState (gc=0x7ef95380, gc@entry=0x21bd96c, 
chipCtx=0x0, chipCtx@entry=0x2217814) at src/chip/gc_chip_state.c:2634
#4  0x681c6da8 in __glChipDrawValidateState (gc=0x21bd96c) at 
src/chip/gc_chip_draw.c:5217
#5  0x68195688 in __glDrawValidateState (gc=0x21bd96c) at 
src/glcore/gc_es_draw.c:585
#6  __glDrawPrimitive (gc=0x21bd96c, mode=<optimized out>) at 
src/glcore/gc_es_draw.c:943
#7  0x68171048 in glDrawArrays (mode=4, first=6, count=6) at 
src/glcore/gc_es_api.c:399
#8  0x76c9ac72 in CEGUI::OpenGL3GeometryBuffer::draw() const () from 
/usr/lib/libCEGUIOpenGLRenderer-0.so.2
#9  0x76dd1aee in CEGUI::RenderQueue::draw() const () from 
/usr/lib/libCEGUIBase-0.so.2
#10 0x76e317d8 in CEGUI::RenderingSurface::draw(CEGUI::RenderQueue const&, 
CEGUI::RenderQueueEventArgs&) () from /usr/lib/libCEGUIBase-0.so.2
#11 0x76e31838 in CEGUI::RenderingSurface::drawContent() () from 
/usr/lib/libCEGUIBase-0.so.2
#12 0x76e36d30 in CEGUI::GUIContext::drawContent() () from 
/usr/lib/libCEGUIBase-0.so.2
#13 0x76e31710 in CEGUI::RenderingSurface::draw() () from 
/usr/lib/libCEGUIBase-0.so.2
#14 0x001bf79c in tengri::gui::cegui::System::Impl::draw (this=0x2374f08) at 
codebase/src/gui/cegui/system.cpp:107
#15 tengri::gui::cegui::System::draw (this=this@entry=0x2374e74) at 
codebase/src/gui/cegui/system.cpp:212
#16 0x000b151e in falcon::osd::view::MainWindowBase::Impl::preNativeUpdate 
(this=0x2374e10) at codebase/src/osd/view/MainWindow.cpp:51
#17 falcon::osd::view::MainWindowBase::preNativeUpdate 
(this=this@entry=0x209fe30) at codebase/src/osd/view/MainWindow.cpp:91
#18 0x000c4686 in falcon::osd::view::FBMainWindow::update (this=0x209fe00) 
at 
codebase/include/falcon/osd/view/FBMainWindow.h:56
#19 falcon::osd::view::App::Impl::execute (this=0x209fdb0) at 
codebase/src/osd/view/app_view_osd_falcon.cpp:139
#20 falcon::osd::view::App::execute (this=<optimized out>) at 
codebase/src/osd/view/app_view_osd_falcon.cpp:176
#21 0x000475f6 in falcon::osd::App::execute (this=this@entry=0x7ef95c84) at 
codebase/src/osd/app_osd_falcon.cpp:75
#22 0x00047598 in main () at codebase/src/main.cpp:5
(gdb) Quit
```

Here I have attached NXP tool calibration results for 2 good boards and 1 bad(getting segmentation faults) board. Click on following links.

[Board 1](https://pastebin.com/iQPt00er)
[Board 2](https://pastebin.com/DJr3HpdR)
[Board 3](https://pastebin.com/a6J6yuzZ)

I did stress test using stressapptest and it was a over night test. But I didn't get any fault and test was passed.

1. From above 3 boards Board 1 and Board 2 are working really well and Board 3 is getting kernel panics while running same application on 3 boards. Can you help me to figure out any clue from this results from above 3 boards ?
2. I did 50 units of production 6 months ago and only 30 were worked properly. But that is with Alliance memory AS4C256M16D3A-12BCN. So will this be an issue of the design ? If this is an issue of the ddr layout or whole design why some boards are working really well ?
3. Will this be an issue of the manufacturing side ? Then how this could be happen with the same production ? Because some are working and some are not.
4. Will stressapptest stress power as well. Do you know any linux app which can stress power as well?

I don't have much experience with mass production and but I like to move forward after learning and correcting this issues. I must be thankful to you if you will kindly reply me soon.

Comment: If you vary the hardware and the problem disappears, your software is OK, your HW design sketchy, and the problematic devices are just faulty. A memory test tool can only find problems, but it cannot prove their absence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not even software.